# CSS3 Pie Border-radius Circle showing thin border

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie

I have created a circle using css3 border-radius and css3pie. Here is a link:

http://www.jamfactory.co.za/tools/circle.html

The problem is on IE the background color exceeds the border color by 1px which does not occur in any other browser. Does anyone know of a method or a fix?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#OuterCircle {
position:relative;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
background:#e21e36;
}
.circle {
-webkit-border-radius: 60px;
-moz-border-radius: 60px;
border-radius: 60px;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="OuterCircle" class="circle">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working properly.

Used a combination of wrappers and absolute positioning

Thanks